# Boolean algebra simplifcation

Tags: boolean, algebra

I'm doing a past paper for my exam on Thursday, and I'm struggling with boolean algebra a bit.
One question asked me to simplify:

```
[(X + Y).(X + 'Y)]
```

I can simplify most of it. I got it down to

```
[X(1 + 'Y + Y)]
```

The mark scheme says this is equal to `[X]`.

But I don't quite understand why - I guess it's because of the

```
['Y + Y]
```

but we're not using the '+' symbol to add them, so why is it like this?

Comment: X or not X === true; true or true === true; X and true === X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from `X * (1 + 'Y + Y)`, note that `'Y + Y == 1` for any `Y` because either `Y` is `1` or else `'Y` is, so `Y + 'Y` is `1 + 0` or `0 + 1`, which in both cases equals `1`.

That would make the function equivalent to `X * (1 + 1)`, but we also know that `1 + 1 == 1` (true OR true is true) and also `X * 1 == X` (`X` AND true is `X`), so in the end you are left with just `X`.

Reference: [Laws of Boolean algebra](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/boolalgebra/index.html), also in a convenient [2-page PDF](http://www.nayuki.io/res/boolean-algebra-laws/boolean-algebra-laws.pdf).

Comment: +1 cos I was slow... and this is better

Comment: The PDF is 3 pages =)

Answer (score 1):

```
['Y + Y]
```

> X + X' = 1 Now imagine picking one between a value and its opposite.
>   Since we are referring to Boolean logic, the only options are going to
>   be 0 or 1. Now see what is the output of the OR operation between 0
>   and its opposite, i.e. 1. Or see what 1 OR 0 yields. Both yield a 1,
>   which means that the output of an OR operation between a value and its
>   negative (opposite), is 1.

http://www.buzzle.com/articles/boolean-algebra-rules.html

Answer (score 0):

In Boolean algebra, If `A = 1, A' = 0` and `A = true, A' = false`. Also every AND operation is (.) and every or operation is (+).

Let me simplify the expression :

```
(X+Y)(X+'Y)
= XX + XY' + YX + YY'
= X + XY' + YX + 0 // since X.X = X & Y.Y'= 0
= X + XY' + XY // = X(1 + 'Y + Y)
= X + X(Y+Y') 
= X + X(1) // Y+Y' = 1
= X + X 
= X
```